# Front end signup in yii2 with using module

Tags: module, yii2

Can anyone help me how to do user sign-up and login from frontend step by step using module in yii-advanced. I am new in yii.

Answer (score 0):

Check the coding of these files. Login and registration are already done in advanced app, check **user.php** and **LoginForm.php** in common/models and **siteController** in frontend/controllers.